# Facebook app count top users

Tags: mysql, facebook, apprequests

I'm using facebook requests in my app. Lets say for example i have a table like this in my db:

```
fb_user_id request_id outstanding
id1        rid1       1
id1        rid2       0
id1        rid3       0
id2        rid4       1
id2        rid5       0
id2        rid6       0
id3        rid7       0
```

outstanding becomes 0 when a user accepts the request. The logic is when the field outstanding is 0 the user that made that request gets 10 points in my app.

Which is the syntax for a mysql query to find out top 100 users with higher points? Ι suppose using order and group by statements..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 100
   fb_user_id
   SUM(outstanding) As OutstandingTotal
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY
   fb_user_id
ORDER BY DESC
   SUM(outstanding)
```